# I do not understand the difference between redux and react-hook-form. What is the difference?

Tags: reactjs

I do not understand the difference between redux and react-hook-form. What is the difference?
(I am only somewhat aware of the fact that both are tools to manage the state of the system.)

Comment: This is rather like comparing apples to oranges: the two libraries don't have a lot of specific overlap. Is there some specific part of their documentation that's confusing you? As it stands an open ended question like this [might be off topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

redux is a library and architecture for **global state** management.
react-hook-form is a **form-specific validation (and form control) hook**.

I think that the state of the **form is basically treated as "local state"**,
so it should be treated as something different from redux.